# Not able to getting array by parsing its showing as string format in Swift 3.2

Tags: ios, arrays, json, iphone, swift

I am doing parsing for my server response in Swift 3.2 version. And I am little new to Swift.

The response is from server

```
response object:{
    data =     (
                {
            "day_time" = "04/12/2017";
            series =             (
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                0,
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1"
            );
        },
                {
            "day_time" = "05/12/2017";
            series =             (
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1",
                "0.1"
            );
        },            

    );
    msg = "user found";
}
```

So, here I have to fetch all `"day_time" and "series"` values. Because, my requirement is user will provide particular date, if that date is matches with `"day_time" key data`, then I have to get  `"series"` data for that index.

So, I have done parsing like this

```
    if responseDictionary.count > 0 {
                    let obj  =  responseDictionary.value(forKey:"data") as! NSArray
                    for i in 0 ..< obj.count  {
                        let timeStamp = obj.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary
                        print("timeStamp object:\(timeStamp)")
                        if (timeStamp.value(forKey: "day_time") != nil) {
                                self.ActionsDBDictionary["series"] = (timeStamp.value(forKey: "series")!)
                                self.ActionsDBDictionary["day_time"] = timeStamp.value(forKey: "day_time")! as! String
                                self.ActionsDBArray.append(self.ActionsDBDictionary)

                        }
                    }
                  }
```

So, while validating user input data matches or not, doing following

```
for peopleDict in ActionsDBArray {
                    if let dict = peopleDict as? [String: Any], let dayTimeArray = dict["day_time"] as? String {
                        datesFromDBArray.append(dayTimeArray)
                    }
                    if let dict = peopleDict as? [String: Any], let ActionArray = dict["series"] as? [Any] {
                        ActionsDBDataArray.append(ActionArray)
                    }
                }
                var seriesArray = [String]()

            let str =  selectedDate.components(separatedBy: "/").first
            for(index , value) in datesFromDBArray.enumerated() {
                if str == value.components(separatedBy: "/").first! {
                    seriesArray.append("\(ActionsDBDataArray[index])")
                }
              }
                print("seriesArray \(seriesArray)")
                for eachElement in seriesArray {
                    totalFilterActionArray.append(eachElement)
                }

(lldb) po totalFilterActionArray
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : "[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]"
```

Its coming as String instead of Array. How can I fix this? Any suggestions.

Comment: Can you not talk to the "server guys" to return something in a proper data format like JSON or XML?

Comment: Proper? its valid json data only.

Comment: *If* it were proper JSON you should parse it as such, **not** do manual string operations. But unfortunately it is not JSON, all the `(` are invalid for example. So either what you have shown here is not what the server actually returns or the server does not return JSON, plug it into https://jsonlint.com/ for "proof".

Comment: @luk2302 That's an NSDictionary's output, not JSON output. He apparently has already converted the JSON to an NSDictionary (hence the variable name `responseDictionary`.) That's my guess at least.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper Can you add the actual JSON that comes back from the server?

Comment: sure, give me few mins

Comment: @DanielT. updated please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are working off some very old sample code, possibly even Objective-C sample code? At any rate, I suggest you parse your data out of the dictionary and into objects so it will be easier to work with.

Something like this:

```
// give it a more descriptive name than `Thing`
struct Thing {
    let dayTime: String
    let series: [Double]
}

extension Thing {
    init(dict: [String: Any]) {
        dayTime = dict["day_time"] as! String
        series = (dict["series"] as! [Double])
        // The above line might need to be as below instead:
        //series = (dict["series"] as! [String]).flatMap { Double($0) }
    }
}

let things = (responseDictionary["data"] as! [[String: Any]]).map { Thing(dict: $0) }
```

Note that the `responseDictionary` referenced above is the variable that you already have.

You can get a particular series like this:

```
let selectedDate = "04/12/2017"

if let index = things.index(where: { $0.dayTime == selectedDate }) {
    print("series:", things[index].series)
}
```

Comment: Here, how can I fetch if user input date is matched, that time, that date index for Series array have to get.

Comment: Thanks for the great response, here confusion is Thing? I took as NSDictioanry, but, let things = (responseDictionary["data"] as! [[String: Any]]).map { Thing(dict: $0) }
here Thing(dict:$0)} did not understand.

Comment: Cannot assign value of type '[viewcontroller.inAppData]' to type 'NSDictionary'

Comment: struct inAppData {
        let dayTime: String
        let series: [Double]
        init(dict: [String: Any]) {
            dayTime = dict["day_time"] as! String
            series = (dict["series"] as! [Double])
            // The above line might need to be as below instead:
            //series = (dict["series"] as! [String]).flatMap { Double($0) }
        }
    }

Comment: self.inAppActionsData = (responseDictionary["data"] as! [[String: Any]]).map { inAppData(dict: $0) }

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper `Thing` is not an NSDictionary. It's a Thing. That line of code converts the NSDictionary called `responseDictionary` into an array of Things. It grabs the "data" out of the dictionary, assumes it's an array of dictionaries and transforms ("maps") each inner dictionary into a Thing.

Comment: but, here extension, should be out of viewcontroller, then, how can we access objects?

Comment: It sounds like this is the first programming language you are learning? In any case, create a separate question.

Comment: I am lit bit new to swift

Comment: I understand your code and followed, but, while accessing                                     if let index = inAppActionsResponse.index(where: { $0.dayTime == selectedDate }) {
showing error as Type 'inAPpActionsResponse' has no member 'index' and here inAppActions is the Things I renamed.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your suggestions, I accepted your answer and upvoted.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper Your 'inAppActionsResponse' is not an array while my 'things' is, so they are not the same.

Comment: If I want to access that, how can I store it, or how to make global declaration for that?